# Copy and Append Rows to New Sheet If Condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying rows in the sheet called Prioritization List (containing 60 rows), which have the word "Done" or done in column 1, to another sheet called Finished Projects. Finished Projects has pre-existing rows, so I am appending to the bottom + 1 row.

So far, the appending works, and there is no error message. But the problem is that only rows 58 and 60 copy over. Row 59 is skipped. I do not know why.

Please advise. Thanks!

```
Sub DeleteOldProject()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prioritization List").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Dim x As Long
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim MaxRowList As Long
    'Dim MaxRowDone As Integer
    Dim S As String

    iCol = 1 'Filter on column A
    MaxRowList = Worksheets("Prioritization List").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'For x = Cells(MaxRowList + 1, iCol).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    For x = 1 To Cells(MaxRowList, iCol).Row 'Step 1
        S = Cells(x, 1).Value
        'MaxRowDone = Worksheets("Finished Projects").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Sheets("Prioritization List").Select
        If S Like "Done" Or S Like "done" Then

            Sheets("Prioritization List").Select
            Rows(x).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Finished Projects").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
'
'            Sheets("Prioritization List").Select
'            Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete

        End If
    Next

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain particularly why it's not working, but your practices are flawed. I tried to clean your function up a bit to improve stability. It's not tested, unfortunately, but it should work juuuust fine...

Try this :

```
Sub ImprovedVersionMaybe()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim MaxRowList As Long
    Dim S As String

    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Prioritization List")
    Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Finished Projects")

    iCol = 1
    MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = MaxRowList to 1 Step -1
        S = wsSource.Cells(x, 1)
        If S = "Done" Or S = "done" Then
            AfterLastTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsSource.Rows(x).Copy
            wsTarget.Rows(AfterLastTarget).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wsSource.Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT :** I will happily detail on the *improvements* I made upon request.

Comment: Thanks! It works. If I want to delete the row from wsSource (after it has been copied over to the wsTarget), how should I code that? I tried adding the following line inside the If Loop at the end, but the code just deletes row 58 and 60, and skips 59: loopSource.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: wsSource.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: See my revised answer ;)

Comment: Thanks much Bernard! It works. Why does it need to be change from forward step to backward step?

Comment: Because when it deletes a row (for example, row 58), the next row (row 59) slides up to the current row (row 58). Therefore when it goes to the next iteration (row 59), it doesn't find what used to be row 59 (which is now at 58). Going backwards allows not to skip the next line following a deletion : deleting row 59 slides row 60 in its place, and row 58 (which is next to be treated) isn't moved. I hope I'm clear enough! If so, I'd very much appreciate you'd mark the question as answered. If not, I'll try to make myself clearer.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Got it - the check mark is now green. Thanks much!

Comment: You, sir, are too kind :)